Is there a way to make Mathematica waiting for Speak to finish speaking?
I wish Mathematica would wait until Speak stops speaking before moving on to the next command, but I couldn't think of anything better than
mySpeak[text_String] := Module[{phrases}
  , 
  phrases = 
   StringSplit[
    StringReplace[text, (# -> # <> "\n") & /@ {".", ";", "!", "?"}], 
    "\n"];
  Do[
   Speak[phrases[[i]]];
   Pause[0.4+0.2*StringLength[phrases[[i]]]];
   , {i, Length@phrases}
   ]
  ]

Is there a better solution?

I don't think this is possible here. The phrase gets sent to the system tts and there's no callback to Mathematica or way of polling that it has finished.
